# MenuItem Icon not visible at runtime

Tags: xaml

I know this is a simple question, but I haven't found any answer that helps me solve my issue. 
Can someone tell me why I can see the icons in the designer, but not at runtime? The XAML that contains the menu items is below. I did try adding the icon/image to the Application.Resources in App.xaml, as you can see in the first menu item, but that still didn't work...see below for the markup in my App.xaml.

```
<Menu Margin="0,0,135,0">
<MenuItem x:Name="DownLoadReportMi" Header="_File" Click="DownLoadReportMI_Click"         HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
            <MenuItem Header="_DownLoad Report..." Icon="{DynamicResource     DownLoadIcon}"/> <!--Icon="{DynamicResource DownLoadIcon}"--> 
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Request Report...">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="UpLoadIcon.png" Height="24" Width="24" x:Name="UpLoadIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>                                              
                </MenuItem.Icon>                    
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="ExitMi" Header="_Exit..." Click="ExitMenuItem_Click" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="ExitIcon.png"  Height="24" Width="24" x:Name="ExitIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <MenuItem Header="_About...">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="HelpIcon.png" Height="24" Width="24" x:Name="HelpIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Image x:Key="DownLoadIcon" Source="DownLoadIcon.png"/>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="GredientBg">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="2,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.142" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#FF176393"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Do you have the build action for the images set to Content or Resource? I would assume it's a file path issue.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both but they still don't appear at run-time.

Comment: ya but are you using full file paths or like blah;component/image/path/blah.png if set as resource?

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I was not using full paths. Thanks Chris W. for the help!!